# make websockets for broadcasting (push) data

Tags: node.js, websocket, broadcast

need help for making websockets broadcast. i'm trying to broadcast data (images) to a browser, and the browser will refresh only if there's a change of the images. the clients will be anyone who access the web.

Comment: So basically you are saying "I'm trying to send data over the internet, help". Specify your problem. Show us what you've tried and what you are expecting to happen. Give us some code, tell us what framework you are using. Details, details! You haven't even mentioned Node.js although you're using that tag and that's an important info, etc. etc.

Comment: i'm sorry for asking this, but i'm new in here, can u help me to tell how to post the code, cos i'm trying to copy paste, but the space isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you host and serve the image via HTTP, having the image URL change whenever the image changes (e.g. by appending a number), publish the new image URL over WebSocket, and then just set the new URL to the image `src` attribute using JavaScript. Simple, will do the job, no hassles.